# Django REST Framework: custom serializer variables

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am using a model serializer (many=True) in Django Rest Framework where I want to return booking_color and text_color properties in JSON in order to display a booking instance on a calendar plugin. Both properties depend on job_type and job_status variables that are calculated (using foreign keys, etc.).  I want to run a calculation for those variables when a particular instance gets initialized (in the init method) so that both calculated values then become available for both method fields (booking_color and text_color). The init method, however, passes entire queryset as 'inst' and so I can't do instance-specific calculations. What would be the best way around this? I have previously ran those calculations in the first method in the list ('get_booking_color' in this case) and it works, but it isn't very elegant and I am not sure if I am supposed to do it.

```
class CalendarView(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    booking_color = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    text_color = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def __init__(self, inst):
        self.job_type = [complicated calculation that depends on inst values]
        self.invoice_status = [complicated calculation that depends on inst values]


    def get_booking_color(self, inst):
        if self.invoice_status == 1:
            if self.job_type == 1:
                return "#000000"
            elif self.job_type == 2:
                return "#f1c40f"
            elif self.job_type == 3:
                return "#FFFFF"
        else:
            return '#faase4'


    def get_text_color(self, inst):
        if self.invoice_status == 2:
            if self.job_type == 1:
                return "#BBFF33"
            elif self.job_type == 2:
                return "#272844"
            elif self.job_type == 3:
                return "#2c0716"
        else:
            return '#FFFFF'
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to modify your `__init__()` call to this:

```
     def __init__(self, instance=None, data=empty, **kwargs):
         self.job_type = [complicated calculation that depends on inst values]
         self.invoice_status = [complicated calculation that depends on inst values]
         super(CalendarViewSerializer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

I'd also recommend renaming your class to `CalendarViewSerializer` so it is not confused with anythign else.

You may also be able to move around overriding the `__init__()` call by passing in those calculations via the context - then working with them from there...e.g.,

```
serializer = CalendarViewSerializer(data=request.data, context={'job_type': ..., 'invoice_status': ...})
```

```
class CalendarViewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    booking_color = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    text_color = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_booking_color(self, inst):
        if self.context['invoice_status'] == 1:
            if self.context['job_type'] == 1:
                return "#000"
            elif self.context['job_type'] == 2:
                return "#f1c40f"
            elif self.context['job_type'] == 3:
                return "#fff"
            else:
                return '#faase4'

    def get_text_color(self, inst):
        if self.context['invoice_status'] == 2:
            if self.context['job_type'] == 1:
                return "#bbff33"
            elif self.context['job_type'] == 2:
                return "#272844"
            elif self.context['job_type'] == 3:
                return "#2c0716"
            else:
                return '#fff'
```

As an extra bonus, I believe you could use some sort of `dict()`/`{}` object to return the hex codes from a key lookup, rather than the `if elseif elseif else` statements.

Comment: I have changed the initialization but I still can't access the specific instance that is being serialized so I can't calculate job_type and invoice_status for each specific instance. The new init method has empty instance, data and kwargs, and if I print 'self' then it gives me the full queryset (this is a many=True serializer) so I can't do instance-specific calculations. You are right about using a dict instead of an if statement, thanks.